# How can i write an Amazon SQS Consumer? {JAVA}

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, events, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

I have a service that sends data to SQS which is working perfectly (code same as seen from Amazon Java SDK) while writing the consumer to read these messages in another queue I am facing issues. The function is never called? Again, the consumer code is also the same as that from the SDK, do I need to provide something else? Or are some more configurations required which are not present in the SDK?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqZ2u.png)

I have also attached the code which I have seen from the SDK. I am doing long-polling as well.

Comment: What do you mean "the function never gets called"? What function specifically? SQS doesn't call your function for you. You have to call that code in step 4 of your screenshot every time you want to receive messages.

Comment: Please don't put text inside images. Update your question with the text shown in the image as text.